# user need to submit the feedback and in my models I'm having user field which is associated with User instance, now don't want to expose my user filed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Users need to submit feedback, and in my models, there's a "user" field associated with a User instance. I want to ensure that this "user" field remains confidential, so it is not identifiable to other individuals when they access the database. Additionally, I need a mechanism to prevent users from submitting feedback more than once. Validation should be in place to ensure that feedback can only be submitted once.

Here is what I tried

models.py

```
class Trainer_Feedback(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    satisfaction_rate  = models.IntegerField()
    addressed_questions_or_not = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    were_training_materials_clear_ornot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    were_training_engaging_interactive = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    opportunity_given_to_participate_or_not = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    training_content_meet_expectation_ornot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    complex_concepts_clearly_explained_ornot = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    which_activity_method_you_found_beneficial = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    aspects_of_training_which_could_improved = models.TextField()
    Suggestions= models.TextField()
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def trainer_feedback(request):
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            session_id = data.get('session_id')
            try:
                user = validate_session(session_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Invalid session ID'}, status=401)

            existing_feedback = Trainer_Feedback.objects.filter(user=user).first()
            if existing_feedback:
                return JsonResponse({'message': 'Feedback already submitted by this user'}, status=400)

            feedback = data.get('feedback')

            satisfaction_rate = feedback.get('1')
            addressed_questions_or_not = feedback.get('2')
            were_training_materials_clear_ornot = feedback.get('3')
            were_training_engaging_interactive = feedback.get('4')
            opportunity_given_to_participate_or_not = feedback.get('5')
            training_content_meet_expectation_ornot = feedback.get('6')
            complex_concepts_clearly_explained_ornot = feedback.get('7')
            which_activity_method_you_found_beneficial = feedback.get('8')
            aspects_of_training_which_could_improved = feedback.get('9')
            Suggestions = feedback.get('10')
            feedback_data = Trainer_Feedback(
                user=user,
                satisfaction_rate=satisfaction_rate,
                addressed_questions_or_not=addressed_questions_or_not,
                were_training_materials_clear_ornot=were_training_materials_clear_ornot,
                were_training_engaging_interactive=were_training_engaging_interactive,
                opportunity_given_to_participate_or_not=opportunity_given_to_participate_or_not,
                training_content_meet_expectation_ornot=training_content_meet_expectation_ornot,
                complex_concepts_clearly_explained_ornot=complex_concepts_clearly_explained_ornot,
                which_activity_method_you_found_beneficial=which_activity_method_you_found_beneficial,
                aspects_of_training_which_could_improved=aspects_of_training_which_could_improved,
                Suggestions=Suggestions
            )
            feedback_data.save()

            return JsonResponse({'message':'Feedback submitted successfully'})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'message':'Invalid request method'}, status=400)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Something went wrong"}, status=500)
```

Can you please help me in this

Comment: You could use a cryptographic hash function on the user's `id` and use that as an `unique` field on the feedback model.